# NSComparisonResult doesnot produce correct result

Tags: iphone

I need to compare two time which is in the below format.

NSDate *dt1;

NSDate *dt2;

NSComparisonResult *cr = [dt1 compare:dt2];
the comparison doesnt consider the AM/PM and produces wrong results.

For Eg: If the time is 6.12 PM, then the results are correct during comparison. But if it is 6.12 AM it still considers as 6.12PM.

Please help me in fixing the issue related to AM/PM. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're highly confused.

```
NSDate *dt1 = 4:30 AM;
```

is not even remotely close to valid syntax. What is your actual object?

I'm guessing here that you don't actually have 2 `NSDate*` objects, but rather have something else.